# How to manage Push notifications from pub\sub using JobQueue?

Tags: asynchronous, connection, zeromq, nonblocking, python-telegram-bot

I am using `ConversationHandler` to manage my boot's states.
I also have some timers there, so i am using `JobQueue` that for.
Also i have web application where user can perform some tasks, after tasks complete i whant it (site) to send notification to user from bot. To interconnect between user and telegram bot i decided to use ZeroMQ (using this example https://gist.github.com/ramn/7061042)
But, i need to run listener somehow async in my bot's code, otherwise it didn't event start to execute due bot's `start_polling` function. I did try to do it using `JobQueue` and it worked great, but it stops all the `JobQueue` queue =(
How can i manage this interconnection? Should i stop using JobQueue and move to some celery-like library?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if this would completely help, but `python-telegram-bot` has a `@run_async` decorator which provides you extra threads for async functions.
You can do `from telegram.ext.dispatcher import run_async` and then decorate the job function.

More details can be found in the [wiki here](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/wiki/Performance-Optimizations#multithreading).